# How to get dynamic textbox values in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

On button click event, I add some text box in my web page, so now I want to get the value of that textbox which was entered by the user. How can I do this?

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  var max_fields      = 100; 
  var wrapper         = $("#test1");
  var add_button      = $("#eassy");
  var x = 1; 
  $(add_button).click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      if(x < max_fields)
      {
        //max input box allowed
        x++; 
        $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="pay"></div>');
      }
  });
});
```

I use this to dynamically create textboxes. Please give me some guidelines!

Comment: value of each textbox or only of added textbox?

Comment: There should be unique name for each textbox.

Comment: @CodeLღver I don't think that is necessary. Please see my answer.

Comment: in here values add by user? so want to track all the values

Comment: @P5Coder from where you will get the value of `$max_fields` is it assuming by you... max_fields variable is assign in javascript not in PHP.

Comment: @CodeLღver First thing, it is very simple to get the value `$max_fields` in PHP from javascript. And other way, you can go on accessing values until `isset($_POST['pay'][$i])`.

Answer (score 0):

You need give unique name to each textbox:

Do this:

```
if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
    $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="pay[]"></div>');
    x++; 
}
```

You will get the value of all textbox in array. You can see the value of each by:

```
print_r($_REQUEST['pay']);
```

This will be a array and can retrieve by:

```
   foreach($_REQUEST['pay'] as $item){
        echo $item;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there are many textboxes with same name, you should use array of names.
The `append()` call should be like this:

```
$(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="pay[]"></div>');
```

And then in the back-end, you can do:

```
for($i = 0; $i < $max_fields; $i++)
    if(isset($_POST['pay'][$i]))
        $value = $_POST['pay'][$i]; // Use this value of the textbox
    else
        break;
```

**EDIT**
To get `max_fields` in PHP:
HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" id="inpMaxFields" name="inpMaxFields" value="">
```

JQuery:

```
$('#inpMaxFields').val(max_fields);
```

PHP:

```
$max_fields = $_POST['inpMaxFields'];
```

Comment: you are also iterating the loop for and foreach both are loops ... additionally you have added if condition only.

Comment: @CodeLღver Can you please point out where there is `foreach()` in my code. Also, what do you mean by "you have added if condition only"?

Comment: I am saying that you are using for loop and I am using foreach loop for same purpose there is no need to make it diabetes

Comment: in this example, can get this $max_fields like this??